# SQL trigger where it displays columns from two table

Tags: sql

I need to write a SQL trigger that displays the data from columns from two tables. I need this trigger to flow once my Transactions table has a new row added or an existing row updated. this is what I have so far but it isn't working its just printing blank table whenever the table is amended.

```
create or alter trigger  TransactionInfo
on [dbo].[Transactions]
after insert, update
as
begin
    declare @pickupDate date;
    declare @returnDate date;
    declare @Make varchar (25);
    declare @model varchar (25);
    declare @tID int;

    select @pickupDate, @returnDate, @Make, @model, @tID
    from[dbo].[Transactions], [dbo].[CAR]
end
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Also: triggers work in the background - they don't *display data from columns* or anything like that. Triggers will add entries to an audit table, or update some select columns - but they don't output or print or display anything ....

Comment: In addition to @marc_s comments, you declare variables that are not populated, thus this `select` from tables will not return anything

Comment: Sql Server triggers can return resulset currently. Note Returning Results
[The ability to return results from triggers will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Triggers that return result sets may cause unexpected behavior in applications that aren't designed to work with them.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#general-trigger-considerations)